# mysql procedure return only one/first row

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying now for the 100 time to find out the reason why my code give as output only the first row. I made one procedure which select all products and I called it in php in that way:

```
$query      = "CALL create_helper()";
$exec       = mysql_query( $query, $connexion );

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($exec)) {
   var_dump(  $row  );
}


CREATE PROCEDURE create_helper ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE prod CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM pC;
  ...
  OPEN prod;
   pd_loop: LOOP
      FETCH pd INTO id_s;
         IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE pd_loop;
         END IF;
         SELECT name, ag, pdt, pname FROM clt WHERE id = id_s;
         ...
      END LOOP pd_loop;
   CLOSE prod;
END;
```

The Procedure under mysql works fine but the only and the one problem is in php. It shows always the first row.

Comment: Check your procedure code , What it is returning

Comment: add the procedure code , That will explain your problem

Comment: Can you verify that you are 1) connecting to the proper database, 2) you are calling the procedure from the correct schema/database (check that you do not have two copies).

Comment: BTW, note that PHP's mysql_ API is deprecated

Comment: I have edited my post, I added the procedure

Answer (score -1):

```
Try it
```

Returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.

mysql_fetch_row() fetches one row of data from the result associated with the specified result identifier. The row is returned as an array. Each result column is stored in an array offset, starting at offset 0.

```
mysql_fetch_array()

Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array and also it fetches by both associative & numeric array.
<?php
$query      = "CALL create_helper()";
$exec       = mysql_query( $query, $connexion );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)) 
{
  var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

Comment: I already did it, It is the same result. It shows only the first row